# connect drupalgap app to drupal site

Tags: database, javascript

i have a problem and the documentation of drupalgap is not too specific.
I have a site for example "www.mysite.com" and i have in a localhost a site built in drupalgap that i want to connect with "www.mysite.com" and the drupalgap app shows the content of the database stored in mysite. It's possible to achieve that? I installed the services module and configured it but i don't know how to proceed. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: DrupalGap Documentation is going to be found [here](http://drupalgap.org/docs). They have a entire website that talks about how to use DrupalGap.

Comment: The drupalgap documentation didn't give me any info about the problem.

Answer (score 1):

1. Install the DrupalGap SDK on localhost, e.g. /var/www/drupalgap
2. Open its app/settings.js file, and point its site_path to www.mysite.com
3. Launch Google Chrome w/ security disabled and open http://localhost/drupalgap/index.html (if you're in web app mode, or use Ripple if you're in phonegap mode).

More information available here: http://drupalgap.org/node/223